# Where are Custom Attributes stored in AWS Cognito?

Tags: amazon-cognito

I am attempting to stored detailed information about users in my AWS Cognito user pool. I can retrieve the standard attributes, such as name or username, just fine with `user.attributes.phone_number`, however attempting to to the same thing with `user.attributes.custom:MyCustomAttribute` simply yielded an error because of the colon. I have ensured that my custom attributes can be read from across all platforms.

I decided to inspect the return key to see where the custom attributes are supposed to be, to find this:

```
attributes: Object
     email: (...)
     email_verified: (...)
     name: (...)
     phone_number: (...)
     phone_number_verified: (...)
     sub: (...)
     __ob__: Observer {value: {…}, dep: Dep, vmCount: 0}
get email: ƒ reactiveGetter()
set email: ƒ reactiveSetter(newVal)
get email_verified: ƒ reactiveGetter()
set email_verified: ƒ reactiveSetter(newVal)
get name: ƒ reactiveGetter()
set name: ƒ reactiveSetter(newVal)
get phone_number: ƒ reactiveGetter()
set phone_number: ƒ reactiveSetter(newVal)
get phone_number_verified: ƒ reactiveGetter()
set phone_number_verified: ƒ reactiveSetter(newVal)
get sub: ƒ reactiveGetter()
set sub: ƒ reactiveSetter(newVal)
__proto__: Object
```

Where/how am I supposed to be able to retrieve and edit my custom attributes and values? I've theorized that it may be in one of the tokens, but I don't have the experience to really act off of that. It seems that it may also not be showing because there is no data, but I need to know how to access them in the first place to change the data, leaving me in the same place.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that they are stored just fine, EXCEPT you cannot use dot notation to access them. Instead of:

`user.attirbutes.custom:MyAttribute`

You have to use:

`user.attributes['custom:MyAttribute']`

as per [this](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/1084) GitHub discussion, where user annjawn says the above.